# How to get the user that published the comment and time it was created from the database so I can present it to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, comments

I'm creating a forum. I have successfully created a Post model presenting posts in the html view with the user email and created_at time. I have also created a Comment model for replying to posts. I've been following a tutorial and understand most of it, but am lost in now getting the user and created_at values of the comments from the database so I can display them. Even though I did it with the post model, it's different because I'm using partials that display in the show html view from the Post controller, and it's confusing me that both the post and comments are displaying in the post controller show view. (i.e. the comments don't have their own show view). I'm a newbie. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    resources :posts do 
        resources :comments
    end

    root 'posts#index'
end
```

**Migration for create_comments**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
            t.text :comment
            t.references :post, foreign_key: true
            t.references :user, foreign_key: true

            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
        @comment.user = current_user

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
    end
end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.new]) do |f|
    = f.input :comment
    = f.submit
```

**models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

show.html.haml

```
#post_content
    %h1= @post.title

    - if user_allowed_post
        = link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {       confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?"}, class: "button"
        = link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "button"
    - else


    %br
    %br
    %br
    %p= @post.content
    %p
        Published
        = time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)
        by
        = @post.user.email

    #comments
        %h2
            - if @post.comments.size == 1
                = @post.comments.size
                Comment
            - else
                = @post.comments.size 
                Comments


        = render @post.comments


        %h3 Reply to thread
        = render "comments/form"
```

Let me know if you need any other files or info.

Comment: `@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))` what does this line do ? try this `@comment = @post.comments.create(params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id).merge!(user_id: current_user.id))` 

And, try in `rails console` what data is actually getting saved in db.

Comment: sorry mate, I asked the wrong question, I thought that was the problem, but its a bit different, just edited the question, re-read it if u have time, thnx

Comment: If you are rendering `show` action from `PostsController`, then you must have defined `@post` and just below to that you can have a collection of comments for that post using `@comments = @post.comments` .From your view  you can render a partial such as: `render @comments`

Comment: I just put the show html view file up. How do I get the user and created-at values of the comments I make from the database?

Comment: A local variable `comment` will be available to you in your partial `= render @post.comments` . You should be able to do this `= comment.user` and `= comment.created_at`

Comment: haha literally just figured that out a second ago !! but thank you. it worked. I'm just trying to get my head around all over it. Only just started a day or so ago. So I end up missing really easy stuff like that. I don't understand which line of code is telling  it to render my _comment.html.haml file though in the show view. could you explain please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122649/discussion-between-koz-and-dkp).

Answer (score 0):

A local variable `comment` will be available to you in your partial `_comment.html.haml` when you specify `= render @post.comments` .

You should be able to do `= comment.user` and `= comment.created_at` in the partial.